# sourcing a shell script from a perl script

Tags: perl, shell

I have a shell script to change my path permanently to another path. My requirement is to source it using a perl script(perl script has some other code as well and finally it has to source the below shell scipt)

test.sh:

```
!/bin/bash
cd /db/oa/invoke/path
```

test.pl:

```
!/usr/bin/perl
system("source /home/test.sh");
```

but sourcing is not working. I know the command `system("sh /home/test.sh --help")` for shell script execution from perl script. But I need similar command to source the shell script. Please let know, if I am missing any details. I have already seen questions being asked on same topic, but i didn't see a proper solution for sourcing. can anyone help me on this.

Regards Anand

Comment: There is no sane way to do what you are asking.  A subprocess cannot affect its parent's environment.  You would basically have to have Perl `exec` Bash and then have that `exec` Perl back over itself in order to pull this off.

Comment: Also the shebang needs to start with the two characters `#!` in order for it to be syntactically valid and actually useful.

Comment: If you're shell script, as in your example, is only changing directory you can use perl's `chdir` function to change directory. You still have all the issues that have been raised above though.

Answer (score 0):

As @tripleee said, you must exec yourself. Here is how I would do it:

```
if (defined $ENV{TOTO}) {
    print "TOTO is $ENV{TOTO}\n";
} else {
    my $cmd = ". ./source.txt ; exec $^X $0 " . join(' ', @ARGV);
    system ($cmd);
}
```

my script source.txt contains

```
export TOTO=titi
```