# Source and run shell function within perl regex

Tags: regex, bash, function, shell, perl

### The Problem

I am attempting to reuse a shell function I have defined in bash script later on in the script, within a perl cmd execution block.   The call to perl cmd basically needs to to run the defined shell function after matching a piece of the regex (capture group #2).   See code definitions below.

### The Code

The pertinent **function definition** in bash shell script:

```bash
    evalPS() {
        PS_ARGS=$(eval 'echo -en "'${1}'"' | sed -e 's#\\\[##g' -e 's#\\\]##g')
        PS_STR=$((set +x; (PS4="+.$PS_ARGS"; set -x; :) 2>&1) | cut -d':' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f2)
        echo -en "${PS_STR}"
    }
```

The definition above uses some bashisms and hacks to evaluate the users real prompt to a string.

That function needs to be **called within perl** in the next function:

```bash
    remPS() {
        # store evalPS definition
        EVALPS_SOURCE=$(declare -f evalPS)
        # initalize prompt
        eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" &> /dev/null
        # handle args
        ( [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && cat - || cat "${1}" ) |
        # ridiculous regex
        perl -pe 's/^[^\e].*//gs' | 
        perl -s -0777 -e '`'"$EVALPS_SOURCE"'`; while (<>) { s%(.*?\Q$ps1\E)(?{`eval $PROMPT_COMMAND`})|(.*?\Q$ps2\E)(?{$ps2=`$\(evalPS "${PS2}"\)`})|(\Q$ps3\E)|(^\Q$ps4\E+.*?\b)%%g; } continue {print;}' -- \
             -ps1="$(evalPS "${PS1}")" -ps2="$(evalPS "${PS2}")" \
             -ps3="${PS3}" -ps4="${PS4:0:1}" |
        perl -pe 's/(.*?)\e\[[A-Z](\a)*/\1/g'
    }
```

The call to perl could be moved to a separate script but either way the issue is I can not find a way to "import" or "source" the `remPS()` function, within the perl script.   I also tried sourcing the function from a separate file definition, into the perl command. Like so:

```bash
    perl -s -0777 -e '`. /home/anon/Desktop/flyball_labs/scripts/recsesh_lib.sh`; while (<>) { s%(.*?\Q$ps1\E)(?{`eval $PROMPT_COMMAND`})|(.*?\Q$ps2\E)(?{$ps2=`$\(evalPS "${PS2}"\)`})|(\Q$ps3\E)|(^\Q$ps4\E+.*?\b)%%g; } continue {print;}'
    ...
```

Or using the `source` builtin:

```bash
    perl -s -0777 -e '`source /home/anon/Desktop/flyball_labs/scripts/recsesh_lib.sh`; while (<>) { s%(.*?\Q$ps1\E)(?{`eval $PROMPT_COMMAND`})|(.*?\Q$ps2\E)(?{$ps2=`$\(evalPS "${PS2}"\)`})|(\Q$ps3\E)|(^\Q$ps4\E+.*?\b)%%g; } continue {print;}'
    ...
```

And for clarity, the final attempt was passing the function declaration into perl like so:

```bash
    perl -s -0777 -e '`'"$EVALPS_SOURCE"'`; while (<>) { s%(.*?\Q$ps1\E)(?{`eval $PROMPT_COMMAND`})|(.*?\Q$ps2\E)(?{$ps2=`$\(evalPS "${PS2}"\)`})|(\Q$ps3\E)|(^\Q$ps4\E+.*?\b)%%g; } continue {print;}'
    ...
```

### The Results

With no luck in any of the above cases..   It seems that the `.` cmd runs whereas the `source` cmd does not, and the syntax for passing the declaration of the function into perl may not be possible, as shown from the output of my tests:

**Sourcing library definitions w/ `source` cmd**

```bash
    (1)|anon@devbox /tmp|$ remPS "${TEXT_FILE}"
    sh: 1: source: not found
    ...
```

**Sourcing w/ shell `.` cmd**

```bash
    (1)|anon@devbox /tmp|$ remPS "${TEXT_FILE}"
    sh: 1: evalPS: not found
    ...
```

**Passing declaration to perl**

```bash
    (1)|anon@devbox /tmp|$ remPS "${TEXT_FILE}"
    sh: 3: Syntax error: ")" unexpected (expecting "}")
    sh: 1: evalPS: not found
    ...
```

### To summarize

**Q)** How to "import" and run a user defined shell command within perl?

**A)** 2 Possible solutions:

1. source the function from separate file definition
2. pass into perl command from bash using variable expansion

### Sources & Research

Evaluating real bash prompt value:

[how-to-print-current-bash-prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322879/how-to-print-current-bash-prompt)   [echo-expanded-ps1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/echo-expanded-ps1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Note**: I chose this implementation of `evalPS()` because using the `script` cmd workaround was unreliable and using `call bind_variable()` bash function required root privileges (effectively changing user's prompt).

[Perl regex embeded code](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Embedded-Code-Execution-Frequency)

**Note**: the function has to be run after every match of `$PS2` to re-evaluate the new prompt and effectively match the next iteration (as it would in a real shell session).   The use case I have for this is many people have (including myself) set their `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to iterate an integer indicating which line number (or offset from `$PS1`) the current line is, and displayed within `$PS2`.

[running a shell command in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854651/how-can-i-store-the-result-of-a-system-command-in-a-perl-variable)

Sourcing shell code in perl:

[how-to-run-source-command-linux-from-a-perl-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781557/how-to-run-source-command-linux-from-a-perl-script)   [can-we-source-a-shell-script-in-perl-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675646/can-we-source-a-shell-script-in-perl-script)   [sourcing-a-shell-script-from-a-perl-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851830/sourcing-a-shell-script-from-a-perl-script)

Alternatively if anyone knows how to translate my implementation of `evalPS()` into perl code, that would work too, but I believe this is impossible because the evaluated string is obtained using a "set hack" which as far as I know is strictly a bashism.

[how-can-i-translate-a-shell-script-to-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152400/how-can-i-translate-a-shell-script-to-perl)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

### Edit

Some more info on the data being parsed..

The text file looks like the following (`cat -A` output):

```bash
^[]0;anon@ - 3^G^[[1m^[[31m(^[[36m1^[[31m)|^[[33manon^[[32m@^[[34mdevbox ^[[35m/tmp^[[31m|^[[36m^[[37m$ ^[(B^[[mecho test^M$
test^M$
^[[1m^[[31m(^[[36m1^[[31m)|^[[33manon^[[32m@^[[34mdevbox ^[[35m/tmp^[[31m|^[[36m^[[37m$ ^[(B^[[mecho \^M$
^[[1m^[[31m[^[[36m2^[[31m]|^[[33m-^[[32m-^[[34m-^[[35m> ^[(B^[[m\^M$
^[[1m^[[31m[^[[36m3^[[31m]|^[[33m-^[[32m-^[[34m-^[[35m> ^[(B^[[m\^M$
^[[1m^[[31m[^[[36m4^[[31m]|^[[33m-^[[32m-^[[34m-^[[35m> ^[(B^[[mtest^M$
test^M$
^[[1m^[[31m(^[[36m1^[[31m)|^[[33manon^[[32m@^[[34mdevbox ^[[35m/tmp^[[31m|^[[36m^[[37m$ ^[(B^[[mexit^M$
exit^M$
```

Or similarly (`less` formatted):

```bash
ESC]0;anon@ - 3^GESC[1mESC[31m(ESC[36m1ESC[31m)|ESC[33manonESC[32m@ESC[34mdevbox ESC[35m/tmpESC[31m|ESC[36mESC[37m$ ESC(BESC[mecho test
test
ESC[1mESC[31m(ESC[36m1ESC[31m)|ESC[33manonESC[32m@ESC[34mdevbox ESC[35m/tmpESC[31m|ESC[36mESC[37m$ ESC(BESC[mecho \
ESC[1mESC[31m[ESC[36m2ESC[31m]|ESC[33m-ESC[32m-ESC[34m-ESC[35m> ESC(BESC[m\
ESC[1mESC[31m[ESC[36m3ESC[31m]|ESC[33m-ESC[32m-ESC[34m-ESC[35m> ESC(BESC[m\
ESC[1mESC[31m[ESC[36m4ESC[31m]|ESC[33m-ESC[32m-ESC[34m-ESC[35m> ESC(BESC[mtest
test
ESC[1mESC[31m(ESC[36m1ESC[31m)|ESC[33manonESC[32m@ESC[34mdevbox ESC[35m/tmpESC[31m|ESC[36mESC[37m$ ESC(BESC[mexit
exit
```

My `$PROMPT_COMMAND` and corresponding prompts (`$PS1`-`$PS4`) for example:

```bash
PROMPT_COMMAND='TERM_LINE_NO=1'
PS1="\[$(tput bold)\]\[$(tput setaf 1)\](\[$(tput setaf 6)\]\${TERM_LINE_NO}\[$(tput setaf 1)\])|\[$(tput setaf 3)\]\u\[$(tput setaf 2)\]@\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\h \[$(tput setaf 5)\]\w\[$(tput setaf 1)\]|\[$(tput setaf 6)\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[$(tput setaf 7)\]\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
PS2="\[$(tput bold)\]\[$(tput setaf 1)\][\[$(tput setaf 6)\]\$((++TERM_LINE_NO))\[$(tput setaf 1)\]]|\[$(tput setaf 3)\]-\[$(tput setaf 2)\]-\[$(tput setaf 4)\]-\[$(tput setaf 5)\]> \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
PS3=""
PS4="+ "
```

Comment: [`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) might be able to help with this. But this is some pretty dense input, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Try using the dot command (spelled `.`) instead of `source`.  The errors are saying that `sh` doesn't understand `source`, so it probably isn't Bash (or Csh, which is where `source` originated; Bourne shell use the name `.`).  Running multiple copies of Perl feeding into each other is peculiar.  The function you want to use looks ripe for conversion to Perl.  I can't (be bothered to) make out exactly what you're doing, but it looks fiendishly complex — and to this '80s era shell programmer, it looks absurd.

Comment: Sourcing with the `.` command originally from Dash shell gives the 2nd output example. i.e. `sh: 1: evalPS: not found`. The only issue with converting the function to perl is I don't know how to go about doing the "set debug" hack I used in the shell function in perl's syntax.. Essentially I parse the evaluated prompt value from `set -x` ---> what would a comparable perl statement be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to scrap this whole idea and use a better one..

Lets step back first.. Big Picture:
Goal was to make the `script` program output an executable shell script of the entire recorded session.

Back to Answers..
The above implementation was supposed to remove all prompts and control characters from the output of `script` (which is the input examples I gave) and then remove the output of each command (i.e. any line that didn't contain control characters).
Passing the `evalPS` function to `perl` to execute proved to be quite redundant and getting `bash` and `perl` to expand the parameters correctly was a nightmare..

**The Final Solution**
Scrapped the perl regex idea and used a combination of subshell and history redirection to grab the commands for the entire `script` session, while it was running.

The entire implementation looks like this:

```
# log cmds to script file as they are entered (unbuffered)
# spawn script cmd in subshell and wait for it to finish
wait -n
( 
    history -c
    export HISTFILE="${SCRIPT_FILE}"
    shopt -s histappend
    script -q --timing="${TIME_FILE}" "${REC_FILE}"
    history -a
)
...
```

Simple and much easier to read! :)
Hope this helps anyone trying to make their own mods to `script` in the future, cheers!

Comment: **lessons learned** in this post: If you run into a wall with 1 solution, double check your alternatives :)